# Axios request from Vue gets a 404

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am using Axios from Vue to make a simple GET request to Laravel 8. But I am getting a 404 that I do not understand.

My welcome.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My Laravel route file :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('skills', function () {
    return ['Laravel', 'tooling', 'PHP', 'Javascript'];
});
```

I have made a public/app.js file:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    mounted() {

        axios.get('/skills').then(response => console.log(response));
    }
});
```

When I type

```
http://localhost:8000/vue-app/public/skills
```

I correctly get the array from my routes file returned:

```
["Laravel","tooling","PHP","Javascript"]
```

When I type

```
http://localhost:8000/vue-app/public
```

I expect to get the same result, but instead I get an error:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/vue-app/public 404 (Not Found)
```

It looks like Vue never gets to the Axios request?

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Hubert

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a `/skills` route,

```php
Route::get('skills', function () {
    return ['Laravel', 'tooling', 'PHP', 'Javascript'];
});
```

I don't see a route for `http://localhost:8000/vue-app/public`

could try adding

```php
Route::get('', function () {
    return ['home', 'route', 'was', 'missing'];
});
```

to have the route available

Answer (score 0):

The route you created /skills will only work with this url.

If you intend to print something in another route, it must be declared too.

Please, apologize if you already did that, but this is not present in your question.

See the below code:

```
Route::get('', function () { 
    return ['Laravel', 'tooling', 'PHP', 'Javascript'];
});
```

Comment: I have a route for  ' ', I have added my complete routes files in my description above.